# How to add a title over MPMovieplayerViewController and hide it on tap

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, mpmoviewcontroller

I need to add a title over the top toolbar in MPMoviePlayerViewController, and if am playing a video, a user tap should hide the title just like it hide any other controls.

Currently I am adding a UILabel as a subview of moviePlayer view. Though this approach adds a title over the topbar (I am setting the frame accordingly), it does not hide the title when user taps over the screen.

Is there any direct api/hack through which I can get access to the top toolbar of MPMoviePlayerViewController? I am thinking like, if I can add the title as a subView of top toolbar, hiding process will be handled by MPMoviePlayerViewController. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_6_iPhone_Application

Comment: @Mak that link is of no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that my answer is referring to `MPMoviePlayerController`, not `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I would advise you to use it either directly or via its reference on `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

First of all, never ever add anything directly onto `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view. That is prone to have all kinds of weird side-effects and is clearly advised against in the documentation. Instead use its `backgroundView` for hosting your custom stuff or the parent of `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `view` (making it a sibling).

But then again, that won't solve the issue you describe with having that view/label/whatever dis/reappear together with the controls if the user taps or simply waits.

There are ways to do that, but I am afraid those are in the grey-zone - or in other words, have a chance of getting rejected by Apple. In fact its not just a grey-zone but a clear violation of Apple's development guidelines.

Just, I have used this trick in the past on major apps and never got detected/rejected.

First, you need to locate the interface-view of your MPMoviePlayerController instance.

```
/**
 * This quirky hack tries to locate the interface view within the supposingly opaque MPMoviePlayerController
 * view hierachy.
 * @note This has a fat chance of breaking and/or getting rejected by Apple
 *
 * @return interface view reference or nil if none was found
 */
- (UIView *)interfaceView
{
    for (UIView *views in [self.player.view subviews])
    {
        for (UIView *subViews in [views subviews])
        {
            for (UIView *controlView in [subViews subviews])
            {
                if ([controlView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoOverlay")])
                {
                    return controlView;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

UIView *interfaceView = [self interfaceView];
```

Now that you got the instance, simply add your view/label/whatever onto that view.

```
[interfaceView addSubview:myAwesomeCustomView];
```

Comment: fyi - this is changed to "MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView" in iOS seven

Comment: how to use MPVideoPlaybackOverlayView, any suggestion?